# Are these correct uses of “auquel”, “duquel”, and “dont”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

Is this a correct use of *auquel*?

> C'est le garçon auquel je pense

Is this a correct use of *duquel*?

> C'est le bœuf duquel je parle

Is this a correct use of *dont*?

> Il est le professeur dont je parle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### C'est le garçon auquel je pense

Yes, this is correct.

### C'est le bœuf duquel je parle

This is incorrect. "duquel" may be translated as "from who/which", so you should is it in a sentence like this:

> Je parle du pays duquel tu es né

Note that the use of « duquel » is very rare, and seems to be formal. On an oral conversation, I would not use it, I would change the structure of the sentence to avoid it.

### Il est le professeur dont je parle

The usage of "dont" is good, but the beginning is odd. In french, you don't use "il est" when you are describing a person, you will use « c'est », or « c'est lui »:

> C'est le professeur dont je parle
>   C'est lui le professeur dont je t'ai parlé

Using « c'est lui » emphasis the fact that you are talking about THIS person in particular, and not an other one.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I learned that duquel can be like dont except more formal? It's also used for expressions right?

Comment: Indeed, "duquel" is much more formal. But you see here you can't use "duquel" in a sentence where "dont" fits... « duquel » means "from which", whereas « dont » means "of which". And it is kind of difficult to find a sentence using « duquel », since it has a very specific use

Comment: Ah, thank you! That cleared up a lot

Comment: Hmm... What would you use instead? De qui? Or dont?

Comment: In the sentence I gave, I would use « où »